# Calculator functionality not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a calculator and its javascript functionality is not working for some reason. I checked over my code and I am sure I have the right syntax and everything.

Heres the link to my codepen
http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/ojEEGr

Here is the html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator" class="container">
  <div id="screen" class="text-right">
    0
  </div>
  <div id="controls">
    <div id="circle">
      <div class="button equals">
        =
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: ;" class="buttonRow text-center">
      <div class="button">
        AC
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        CE
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        %
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        /
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonRow text-center">
      <div class="button">
        7
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        8
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        9
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        *
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonRow text-center">
      <div class="button">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        5
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        6
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        +
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonRow text-center">
      <div class="button">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        -
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the java script

```js
var entries = [];
var total = 0;
var temp = '';

$(".button").on("click", function() {
  var val = $(this).text();

  // Got a number, add to temp
  if (!isNaN(val) || val === '.') {
    temp += val;
    $("#screen").val(temp.substring(0,10));
    
  // Got some symbol other than equals, add temp to our entries
  // then add our current symbol and clear temp
  } else if (val === 'AC') {
    entries = [];
    temp = '';
    total = 0;
    $("#screen").val('')

  // Clear last entry
  } else if (val === 'CE') {
    temp = '';
    $("#screen").val('')
 
  // Got the equals sign, perform calculation
  } else if (val === '=') {
   entries.push(temp);
    // Definitely not the most elegant
    var newTotal = eval(entries.join('').substring(0, 10))
    $("#screen").val(newTotal);
  entries = [];
    temp = '';
    
  // Push operators
  } else {
    entries.push(temp);
    entries.push(val);
    temp = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: How does it not work right... give a test case and expected result.

Comment: can you be more specific about what isnt working?

Comment: `#screen` is a DIV, yet you're doing `$("#screen").val()`, but DIV's don't have a value. Use `$("#screen").text()` instead.

Comment: `$(this).text()` will include the whitespace like line breaks so the comparisons are never true. Add values to the buttons themselves which is a more robust approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Two main mistakes:

1. You must `.trim()` the text value of your buttons. Because normally, their text is like         `AC`       . So code fix:

   ```
   var val = $(this).text().trim();
   ```
2. You're trying to change `#screen` text by `.val`, which is **only** for `<input>` elements. Instead, use `$("#screen").text()`.

Fixed code with some useful debug messages: http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/hrfeabjy/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues, but adeneo prettey much nailed the primary one. I edited your codepen, check out the link below. Included is a better way of determining button values via a data attribute (see Juhana's comment).

```
<div class="button" data-val="%">
```

Then access it in the js like this:

```
var val = $(this).data("val");
```

I also changed the zindex on the "=" button circle so the whole button was clickable, not just the top half.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yyegzq